# How to model a quiz-system in OOP?

Tags: java, oop, modeling

I am just trying to make a quiz system for young people to learn road/traffic signs.The idea was also to make something in a way that i later can use the same system for other types of quizzes.

I have just started out, and this is what i have planned so far:
(I am doing this in Java)

- Class named Roadsign (name, type, description)
- Class named Question (Roadsign, answer, options)
- Class named Quiz (ArrayList, number of right answers, and so on..)

The idea is that i eventually can use any model, not just Roadsign, inside the Question class. Maybe it also can be done in such a way that you decide inside the Question class what attribute/member of the model class you wish to use as the answer.

I am unsure on how i would model such a system, especially on behalf of the Question class.

Hopes this makes sense, and that someone wants to share me some good ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to model a quiz system where each question consists of an image (in your case Roadsign), a question and answer options, you could do it like that:

- Class named QuestionImage(name, description)
- Class named Question (QuestionImage, question, answer, options)
- Class named Quiz (ArrayList, number of right answers, and so on..)

Each question could then have an image, a question (so that you can also ask questions unlike `What does the image show?`), one right answer, and several wrong answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a couple of interfaces there I can think of QuestionSubject. So then the class Question will be able to use any class that will implement the QuestionSubject interface.

I might also define a class for Answer which will determine the answer structure.